# Is this static_cast safe in different platforms?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

Does this cast have defined behavior in different platforms?

I want to have the pointer address in 64 bits. if the platform is 32 bits, top bits should be all 0 or 1. This is used for some seed generation only used at runtime so it doesn't matter to be either one.

**But it should not be something random or undefined**.

```cpp
long long UniquePointer = static_cast<long long>(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&Param));
```

I can not test this on 32 bit platform right now, So I decided to ask here.

`Param` is just a class member field.

Comment: *"Param is just a class member field."* What is the type of `Param`?

Comment: I'd be more worried about the `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: On 32 bit systems, do you want the top 32 bits to be 0 or 1 depending on what the high bit in the converted pointer is? If so, then perhaps use a signed type rather than `size_t` in the initial cast. There is the `intptr_t` available on most systems.

Comment: @AnoopRana It's `TArray<SomeStruct>`. TArray is an array in unreal engine api. it's a class.

Comment: Why don't you use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`?

Comment: @AdrianMole I would prefer it to be always 0s. But its for seed algorithm, so it should not matter that much.

Comment: So, `size_t` is always unsigned but its size can vary. On most 64 bit systems, it is equivalent to a `unit64_t` and on 32-bit systems it would likely be the same as a `uint32_t`. So, as you have it, there will be no sign extension and the top 32 bits will be zero.

Comment: @DanielLangr Hmm, I didn't know about those. What if I use `intptr_t`?

Comment: The address of Param is likely to be the same from one run to the next, so it's probably not a good seed for a RNG.  If it's not for a RNG what kind of "seed" is it?

Comment: Also, note that there is also `uintptr_t`, if you want to avoid sign extension when converting to the larger type.

Comment: @AdrianMole I've checked and `size_t` is defined to be `unsigned __int64` on 64 bit platforms and `unsigned int` otherwise.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you, so like this `static_cast<long long>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>`? I had a feeling it would work but just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: I would also use the *explicit* `int64_t` rather than `long long`.

Comment: But there may be a "swings and roundabouts" issue here. The `uintptr_t` to `int64_t` will work (always?) on 32 bit systems but that *may* introduce UB on 64 bit systems. Need to check the Standard for what happens if the source isn't representable by the destination type, in that case. :)

Comment: @Den-Jason this one is to get different seed for different Params. I mix the seed with another unique object id which would be different from run to run.

Comment: @Den-Jason it is for RNG. I just wanted to have different seed when I pass different parameter. (the parameter is from a field of a class). I didn't want to pass extra parameter to differentiate seeds like `DoSomething(FieldA, SeedA)` and `DoSomething(FieldB, SeedB)`. so I just thought about taking the address of the given field.

Comment: *"I can not test this on 32 bit platform"* compiler has flag to compile in 32bits mode (`-m32` flag for gcc for example).